# Pycharm で djangoが「未解決の参照」と表示される

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Vagrant(VirtualBox)上のフォルダを参照する形で、ローカルからpycharmを実行しています。
pycharm上でファイルを開くと、例えば

```
from django.conf import settings
```

のsettingsの下に赤線が引かれ、「未解決の参照」と表示されてしまう問題に遭遇しており、解決方法等ご教示いただきたく考えています。

実機OS: Windows 10
VirtualBox OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Python: 3.7
Remote Python: 3.5.2
.boxファイルは他の開発メンバーが使用していたものを流用しています。

設定 → プロジェクト → インタープリター
を見るとDjangoはインストールされているように見えます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

自分のPCにだけ出ている現象のようで、他のメンバーにも見てもらったのですが解決に至っていません。

Comment: このチュートリアルに示されたファイル群のどれか(settings.py?)が出来ていないとか？ [はじめての Django アプリ作成、その 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/3.0/intro/tutorial01/), [Djangoの設定](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/3.0/topics/settings/)

Comment: kunifさん、コメントありがとうございます。
settings.pyにあたるファイルは存在していて、manage.pyから呼び出す記載があります。

Comment: 試しに、pycharmからVirtualBox上に新規プロジェクトを作ってみたのですが、Djangoプロジェクトは「許諾が拒絶されました」と出て作成できませんでした。

一方、Pure Pythonプロジェクトだと、問題なく作成できました。

Comment: 環境として合っているか判りませんが、こんな記事があるようです。[PyCharmのVagrantリモートデバッガ設定](https://qiita.com/s-sanosuke/items/750557c6397e73cd3828), [Remote Python Development Environment using PyCharm and Vagrant](https://medium.com/@krishna.yerramsetty/remote-python-development-environment-using-pycharm-and-vagrant-32f1ac3c66b8), [VMで動作するPyCharmの設定](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/configuring-product-to-work-on-the-vm.html) こちらはローカル [PyCharm Community で Python + Djangoの開発環境を構築する方法](http://doop-web.com/blog/archives/2547)

Answer (score 1):

プロジェクトを開く階層が違うのが原因でした。お騒がせしました…

---

*この投稿は @assezPierre さんが質問文に記載した内容を元に、コミュニティwiki で個別の回答として投稿しました。*